# Hosting services for JEE

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm using EJBS, JPA and GWT. I was wondering if someone knows a hosting service that offers what I need (like a Glassfish or JBoss server).
I need a servlet and an EJB container.

Comment: Google can help you for this kind of question: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hosting+jEE+tomcat#hl=fr&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=web+hosting+j2ee&oq=web+hosting+j2ee&gs_l=serp.3..0i19j0i30i19l3.15236.17295.4.17500.8.7.0.1.1.3.1369.2614.1j0j3j0j1j7-1.6.0...0.0...1c.1.vO246bk8-9Q&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=e2131b2d282449c7&bpcl=40096503&biw=755&bih=887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS(Amazon Web Services).  They let you use Weblogic.